# Why can I not upgrade my svn repository?

Tags: svn

I have a many-year-old subversion repository that I would like to upgrade so that I can migrate it to git. However I keep getting the following error.

```
% svn upgrade /tmp/repo
svn: /build/buildd/subversion-1.7.5/subversion/libsvn_subr/dirent_uri.c:1518:            uri_skip_ancestor: Assertion `svn_uri_is_canonical(parent_uri, ((void *)0))' failed.
[1]    15361 abort      svn upgrade /tmp/repo
```

Why?

Answer (score 0):

svn upgrade perform upgrade for working copies.

If you try upgrade repository (not working copy), then you should perform svnadmin dump / svnadmin load.

If /tmp/repo really is working copy - you can checkout another working copy and remove old.

Comment: I meant working copy (in git there isn't really a difference)

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to upgrade to a newer version of subversion.